# facebook.stackoverflow.com uses an invalid security certificate

Tags: bug

facebook.stackoverflow.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.stackexchange.com , stackexchange.com

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)